# Nested Recycler View skipping frames

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nested-lists

I am using nested recycler view, that is a recycler view inside the rows of another recycler view.
During scroll, it skips frames and is very slow.
What can I do to avoid this?

What some research helped me figure out:-
Use something like epoxy.
Please give some insight into how to solve this?
If I have to use epoxy, please get me some basic code for epoxy.

What I have tried?

Outer recycler view:-

```
val manager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
      manager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager)
      mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)



      /**
       *Below measures help in making the recycler view efficient
       */
      mAgendaAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
      mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30)
      mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)
      mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH)
      mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)


      /*************************************************************
```

Also :-

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ObjectHolder) {



    if(holder!=null){
      holder.recyclerView.adapter =null
      holder.phaseTv.text=null
      holder.unitIdTv.text= null

    }



    super.onViewRecycled(holder)


  }
```

Similar measures for inner recycler view also.
I have used a 2D arraylist as data structure.
The nested recycler view is attached to view holder.

Comment: Have u tried calling mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled in the inner rv as well

Comment: @Debu Yes.. I have done that :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be good for you. I'm using ExpandableRecyclerview to have recyclerview in an other recyclerview : https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: Yes, you can define multiple view types

Comment: What I meant is that does this library provide any kind of support for heterogenous layouts that the native recycler view doesnot give?

Comment: there is no support, you need to implement it (https://medium.com/@bipinAle/heteregenous-recyclerview-android-6d93b5ba3ff4)